# How to use the same CRUD operation in frontend and backend in yii2 advance?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table named Userprofile in the backend which saves the user information including profile image Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/avatar/'; but when i tried to used the same table from the frontend then the image is saved in the frontend as i have used basePath. How can i save the profile pic in same folder and can do CRUD operation from frontend as well as backend?

Answer (score 1):

If you need simply render the related  views  using alias  eg:

if you want use a backend view from front end

```
    class YourControllerController extends Controller
    {
        public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                'verbs' => [
                    'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                    'actions' => [
                        'delete' => ['post'],
                    ],
                ],
            ];
        }

        public function actionIndex()
        {
            $searchModel = new YourModelSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
            $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=15;

            return $this->render('@backend/views/your-controller/index', [
                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);

        }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, i have done for the view part but the real problem is i have use the widget and <a href="/rbac/userprofile/update?id=<?= $model['id']?>">Edit Profile</a> but when i try to edit the profile the image is saved in the frontend as i have used Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/avatar/';. I want to use crud operation for frontend and backend.

Comment: In the way i have posted you can use the same view for backend and frontend ... in this way you should pass a proper var the set the directory where save the image  or assign it i model constant ..

Answer (score 0):

suppose you want to save all images for (frontend and backend) `CRUD` under `frontend/web/uploads`
so in your `backend config file` add this component:

```
'urlManagerFrontEnd' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://front.domain.ext/',//frontend app url
],
```

then use it from the backend controllers or models :

```
 Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontEnd->baseUrl ."/path/to/your/place";
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

> 1. configuration with migration . folder path: common\config\main-local.php

[image]

> 2. create table: client

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
    `client_id`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `first_name`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `middle_name`  varchar(255) NULL ,
    `last_name`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`)
);
```

> 3. go to backend gii example: http://backend.dev/gii

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]